# In electrochemisty, we write delta S= nF(dE/dT)p (at constant pressure), is (dE/dT)p cell constant?

Tags: electrochemistry

My lecturer stated that dE/dT at constant pressure is cell constant, but isnt cell constant of a cell (l/A) the units don't match, is there any other cell constant that he might be talking about?

Answer (score 2):

The lecturer means "a" cell constant, not "the" cell constant in conductometry context.

It is $\Delta_\mathrm{r} S$, not $S$. For a given temperature, it is constant only for standard conditions.

It also depends on temperature, because product and reagent heat capacities are different, so $\left(\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial T}\right)_p$ depends on $T$ too. It could be considered approximately constant for not too wide temperature range.

---

For the temperature dependence, let start with this equation relating the electrochemical and thermodynamic potentials:

$$-nFE^{\circ}(T) = \Delta_\mathrm{r} G^{\circ}(T) = \Delta_\mathrm{r} H^{\circ}(T)   - T \Delta_\mathrm{r} S^{\circ}(T) \tag{1}$$

$$-nF \left(\frac{ \partial E^{\circ}(T)}{\partial T}\right)_p =  \left(\frac{ \partial \Delta G_\mathrm{r}^{\circ}(T)}{\partial T}\right)_p = \\
= \left(\frac{ \partial \Delta H_\mathrm{r}^{\circ}(T)}{\partial T}\right)_p   - T \left(\frac{ \partial \Delta S_\mathrm{r}^{\circ}(T)}{\partial T}\right)_p - \Delta_\mathrm{r} S^{\circ}(T) \tag{2}$$

$$\left(\dfrac{ \partial \Delta H_\mathrm{r}^{\circ}(T)}{\partial T}\right)_p = \Delta C_p(T)\tag{3}$$

$$\left(\dfrac{ \partial \Delta S_\mathrm{r}^{\circ}(T)}{\partial T}\right)_p = \dfrac{\Delta C_p(T)}{T}\tag{4}$$

$$-nF \left(\frac{ \partial E^{\circ}(T)}{\partial T}\right)_p =  \Delta C_p   - \Delta C_p - \Delta_\mathrm{r} S^{\circ}(T) = -\Delta_\mathrm{r} S^{\circ}(T)\tag{5}$$

$$nF \left(\frac{ \partial E^{\circ}(T)}{\partial T}\right)_p = \Delta_\mathrm{r} S^{\circ}(T)\tag{5a}$$

$$\Delta_\mathrm{r} S^{\circ}(T_2)=\Delta_\mathrm{r} S^{\circ}(T_1)+ \int_{T_1}^{T_2}{ \frac{\Delta C_p(T) \mathrm{d}T}{T}}\tag{6}$$

where $\Delta C_p$ is the difference of molar heat capacities of products and reactants (including stoichiometry).

$$ \left(\frac{ \partial^2 E^{\circ}(T)}{\partial T^2}\right)_p =  \frac{\Delta C_p(T)}{nFT}\tag{7}$$

Comment: I added some $\Delta$s on Eqs. (2-5) if you don't mind.

Comment: @MetalStorm  Sure, you are right...